# django model methods not accessible in templates

Tags: django, django-models

I've used model methods many times in templates, but for some reason on this project I'm running into a problem where I can't access the methods in the templates. Take for example this model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    '''
    Data about blog posts. The guts of everything.
    '''
    blog = models.ForeignKey(PersonalBlog)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
        return reverse('blog-post', kwargs={'blog':self.blog.slug, 'post':self.slug})

    def hello(self):
        return 'hello'
```

And then in the template if I do something like:

```
{% for p in posts %}
    <a href="{{ p.get_absolute_url }}"><h3>{{ p.title }}</h3></a>
{% endfor %}
```

I don't get anything back from get_absolute_url. After validating that the method works correctly in terminal, I made a dummy method called hello above. That returns in terminal as well, but nothing shows up in the template. I've restarted the server, and stood on my head while forcing reload. Nothing seems to be working for something that usually is trivial.

I'm guessing it's going to be something stupid on my part, but I haven't been able to find it after way too long of troubleshooting something so simple. Any ideas?

Comment: If there is an error in the method, Django will silence it and it won't print anything. Have you checked `get_absolute_url` actually works and runs properly (e.g., print statement)?

Comment: Yes, i have verified that get_absolute_url returns correctly through the shell

Comment: Does it also work for the particular `Post` object you're trying to view in the template? Note also that there may be a Unicode issue that you won't see in the shell but it does cause a problem in the template.

Comment: Yes the fields on the Post object I can access fine, just the models. I will put in a print to see if I can see anything in the server log that I'm not seeing in shell.

Comment: not your question but move this line `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse` to the top of your file, this will make your code faster

Comment: nothing returned in the print, so I even tried to raise an Exception, and nothing happened either. It's not hitting the method at all?

Comment: @boussouira thanks, usually I always do that but in the django doc for get_absolute_url they put it inside the method, so I thought for kicks and giggles I would see if that changed anything.

Comment: Also, you have an error in your template, this `</a>p.create_date }}</p>` should be `</a>{{ p.create_date }}</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I overlooked it, but the problem was in the view that created the posts object. I'm using TastyPie and in the API call the method was not accessible. Needed to change the API resource to expose the function.